# Hypernym for "coalition" and "opposition"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, hypernyms, politics

I'm looking for a word (or expression) that is a hypernym of *coalition* and *opposition*. I want to be able to ask a party whether its "type", for lack of a better word, is coalition or the opposition without using that word:

> — What is your [*type*]? — Coalition.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: I think your question may be confusing to some. You seem to pre-suppose that all political parties that are in government are part of a coalition and all parties not in government are the opposition (and not in coalition). These conditions don't apply to all systems of government.  

You could ask: "Is your party *in government*?", but that's not a hypernym.

Comment: I don't know of a case where a party can be neither in the coalition nor the opposition. In any case, in Israel (where I live and wish to use this word), it's not possible.

Comment: *Coalition* and *opposition* do not belong to a common superset class, as such no hypernym can exist.

Comment: @Kris: Your argument seems circular to me. Also *coalition* ⊆ *coalition* ∪ *opposition* and *opposition* ⊆ *coalition* ∪ *opposition*. Perhaps you mean that the set *coalition* ∪ *opposition* does not form a [natural kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_kind)

Comment: @AmirRachum: My main point was that for many people coalition is not synonymous with government, often governments are formed by single parties.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully I agree that in many nations this is the case, but I think that Israel's case "often" cannot be applied. There are simply too many parties with a significant share of the Knesset.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest one of:

- [bloc](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bloc?q=bloc): a group of countries or *political parties with common interests who have formed an alliance*
- [faction](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/faction)
- [affiliation](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/affiliation)

There are also a couple of general terms that might also suit:

- side
- camp

They can perhaps answer the question:

> Which ***_*___** do you belong to? – Opposition.

Comment: 'bloc' does seem to remotely fit. However it usually refers to left-wing/right-wing and not coalition/opposition.

Comment: I don't think 'bloc' is restricted to left- or right- politics. It could just simply be a group with common interests or goals.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a binary choice, a party can either be an opposition party or a governing (coalition) party, I would go with *affiliation*:

```
Party affiliation:  ☐ coalition (or government)
                    ☐ opposition
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the term you are looking for is *(party) standing* or *(party) status*.  At least that is the term used here in Canada.

> What is the Tories' standing in Parliament?  They're in government.
>
> What's the status of the Liberals?  They're in opposition.

This may be a Canadianism, though.  There are rules, for example, on when a party attains major party status and with that certain kinds of public funding.

A Google search shows that at least '*party status*' is used in the US as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about “group”, “organization”, “party” or “entity”?

Here are the hypernyms for “coalition” in WordNet:

```
Sense 1
alliance, coalition, alignment, alinement
       => organization, organisation
           => social group
               => group, grouping
                   => abstraction, abstract entity
                       => entity

Sense 2
coalition, fusion
       => union, unification
           => state
               => attribute
                   => abstraction, abstract entity
                       => entity

Sense 3
coalescence, coalescency, coalition, concretion, conglutination
       => union, unification, uniting, conjugation, jointure
           => combination, combining, compounding
               => change of integrity
                   => change
                       => action
                           => act, deed, human action, human activity
                               => event
                                   => psychological feature
                                       => abstraction, abstract entity
                                           => entity
```

And the hypernyms of “opposition” in WordNet:

```
Sense 1
resistance, opposition
       => action
           => act, deed, human action, human activity
               => event
                   => psychological feature
                       => abstraction, abstract entity
                           => entity

Sense 2
opposition, oppositeness
       => relation
           => abstraction, abstract entity
               => entity

Sense 3
confrontation, opposition
       => resistance
           => group action
               => act, deed, human action, human activity
                   => event
                       => psychological feature
                           => abstraction, abstract entity
                               => entity
               => event
                   => psychological feature
                       => abstraction, abstract entity
                           => entity

Sense 4
opposition, opponent, opposite
       => contestant
           => person, individual, someone, somebody, mortal, soul
               => organism, being
                   => living thing, animate thing
                       => whole, unit
                           => object, physical object
                               => physical entity
                                   => entity
               => causal agent, cause, causal agency
                   => physical entity
                       => entity

Sense 5
opposition
       => body
           => social group
               => group, grouping
                   => abstraction, abstract entity
                       => entity

Sense 6
opposition
       => direction
           => position, spatial relation
               => relation
                   => abstraction, abstract entity
                       => entity

Sense 7
enemy, foe, foeman, opposition
       => adversary, antagonist, opponent, opposer, resister
           => person, individual, someone, somebody, mortal, soul
               => organism, being
                   => living thing, animate thing
                       => whole, unit
                           => object, physical object
                               => physical entity
                                   => entity
               => causal agent, cause, causal agency
                   => physical entity
                       => entity

Sense 8
Opposition
       => party, political party
           => organization, organisation
               => social group
                   => group, grouping
                       => abstraction, abstract entity
                           => entity
```

Comment: I don't think these words are appropriate in a political context.

Comment: Actually, what we need a hypernym that encompasses **both** the classes. An umbrella term, so to speak.

Comment: @AmirRachum Sense 8 is clearly the political context. Political Party is the hypernym of Opposition.

Comment: @Kris any word that occurs as a hypernym of both “coalition” and “opposition” should be an umbrella term, shouldn’t it?

Answer (score 0):

*Collaborative leadership style*.